# how to return result in phonegap javascript function?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Hi I'm trying to return the result from the phonegap plugin method.

I'like to do the following code.

```
  function table(tableName)
  {
        var rowCount_i;
        return {
                 tableName : tableName,
                 rowCount : function(){
                 window.plugins.getRowCount(
                                   tableName,
                  function(r)
                  {
                         rowcount_i = r; 
                  }
                  function(e)
                  {
                          alert(e); 
                  }

        );
        return rowCount_i;

     }
 };

 }
```

When i'm tried to run the  following code...

```
  var tbl = new table("psd-person");
  alert(tbl.rowCount);
```

And  the result is **Undefined..**

Is there any way to return the result in rowCount Method or can you show this rowCount method with defferd concept?

Please help me out.. Thanks in advance

Comment: because the function you called (rowCount) dont return anything!

Comment: btw your return rowCount_i; is never called because of the return obove ;)

Comment: but i have returned rowCount_I which is having result object.

Comment: yes but you alert the result of the function not the object! object = alert(tbl); but that will not help you mutch

Comment: you have still one `}` missing at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with callback:

```
function table(tableName)
{
  return {
    tableName : tableName,
    rowCount : function(callback){
      window.plugins.getRowCount(tableName,
        function(r)
        {
               rowcount_i = r; 
               callback(rowcount_i);
        }
        function(e)
        {
                alert(e); 
        });    
    }
  }
}

var tbl = new table("psd-person");
tbl.rowCount(function(rowcount_i) {
  alert(rowcount_i);
});
```

Not tested!

Comment: you cant do it with return, because the plugin also give you a callback. In what way do you want achieve ? Whats your goal ?

Comment: My goal is function rowCount should return the result object.

Comment: with result object you mean the row count ?

Comment: if i do the following code, i did not get the correct result.       rowCount : function() {   return     window.plugins.getRowCount(tableName,
        function(r)
        {
               rowcount_i = r; 
               callback(rowcount_i);
        }
        function(e)
        {
                alert(e); 
        });

Comment: callback is not defined in your code 2 comments above! 
get your callback like this ? http://pastebin.com/TSkvr1Wx

Comment: okay i'll try  pastebin.com/TSkvr1Wx – Cracker0dks 17 secs ago

Comment: In  this code   var tbl = new table("psd-person");
returnCallBack = tbl.rowCount();  , returnCallBack is this same you declared in rowCount function ?

Comment: at the end it has the same value but its not the save var. Better rename the lower and set var in front of it. Otherwise its global.

Comment: i have done these ..var tbl = new table("psd-person");  var returnCallBack = tbl.rowCount(); alert(returnCallback); when i alerted

Comment: when i alerted the returnCallBack.. the result is, it alerted the whole returnCallback function definition;

Comment: you wanted the callback not the result (row count) -.-

Comment: sorry I did not get you..but i need the result oject..so that i can  use the result such as var res = tbl.rowCount; alert(JSON.stringify(r)); something with that result object.

Comment: you cant do this! Because you get a callback!!! You have to put all your following code that needs the result in the callback function! Use my first answer! If you don't undestand why this is not possible read content about callbacks in javascript!